# Extracting event types from last 21 day window

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

My dataframe looks like this. The two rightmost columns are my desired columns.

```
**Name      ActivityType     ActivityDate   Email(last 21 says)  Webinar(last21)**             
John       Email            1/1/2014        NA                   NA   
John       Webinar          1/5/2014        NA                   NA
John       Sale             1/20/2014       Yes                  Yes
John       Webinar          3/25/2014       NA                   NA
John       Sale             4/1/2014        No                   Yes
John       Sale             7/1/2014        No                   No
Tom        Email            1/1/2015        NA                   NA   
Tom        Webinar          1/5/2015        NA                   NA
Tom        Sale             1/20/2015       Yes                  Yes
Tom        Webinar          3/25/2015       NA                   NA
Tom        Sale              4/1/2015        No                   Yes
Tom        Sale              7/1/2015        No                   No
```

I am just trying to create a yes/no variable that denotes whether there was an email or a webinar in the last 21 days for each "Sale" transaction. I was thinking(mock code) along the lines of using dplyr this way:

```
custlife %>% 
group_by(Name) %>% 
 mutate(Email(last21days)=lag(ifelse(ActivityType = "Email" & ActivityDate of email within (activity date of sale - 21),Yes,No)).
```

I am not sure of the way to implement this. Kindly help. Your help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: if you had all days, for example 1/1/2014, 2/1/2014, 3/1/2014 ...  then you could work on `cumsum(Email)` and `lag(x, k = 21)`. By the way, in context of above question, NA Email rows can be skipped. Other inefficient way would be to generate a set of days that had a preceding Email no more than 21 days earlier or the same day. Then do a join with original set.

Comment: Why `Webinar` rows also have "`yes`" on them, aren't you checking just the `Sale` rows?

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right. I made an error while I was making the example. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: where are the data??

Comment: @jangorecki what do you mean? The data is in the question

Comment: @DavidArenburg in OP question there is not data but the way data looks like ;)

Comment: @jangorecki I am very new to stackoverflow. Kindly let me know of an easy way to post the data in stackoverflow.

Comment: @gibbz00 `?dput`, on your data: `dput(custlife[1:20])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution. Here I'm creating 2 temporary data sets- one for `Sale` and one for the rest of activity types and then joining between them by a rolling window of 21 while using `by = .EACHI` in order to check conditions in each join. Then, I'm joining the result to the original data set.

Convert the date column to `Date` class and key the data by Name and Date (for the final/rolling join)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df)[, ActivityDate := as.IDate(ActivityDate, "%m/%d/%Y")], Name, ActivityDate)
```

Create 2 temporary data sets per each activity

```
Saletemp <- df[ActivityType == "Sale", .(Name, ActivityDate)]
Elsetemp <- df[ActivityType != "Sale", .(Name, ActivityDate, ActivityType)]
```

Join by a rolling window of 21 to the sales temporary data set while checking conditions

```
Saletemp[Elsetemp, `:=`(Email21 = as.logical(which(i.ActivityType == "Email")), 
                        Webinar21 = as.logical(which(i.ActivityType == "Webinar"))), 
         roll = -21, by = .EACHI]
```

Join everything back

```
df[Saletemp, `:=`(Email21 = i.Email21, Webinar21 = i.Webinar21)]
df
#     Name ActivityType ActivityDate Email21 Webinar21
#  1: John        Email   2014-01-01      NA        NA
#  2: John      Webinar   2014-01-05      NA        NA
#  3: John         Sale   2014-01-20    TRUE      TRUE
#  4: John      Webinar   2014-03-25      NA        NA
#  5: John         Sale   2014-04-01      NA      TRUE
#  6: John         Sale   2014-07-01      NA        NA
#  7:  Tom        Email   2015-01-01      NA        NA
#  8:  Tom      Webinar   2015-01-05      NA        NA
#  9:  Tom         Sale   2015-01-20    TRUE      TRUE
# 10:  Tom      Webinar   2015-03-25      NA        NA
# 11:  Tom         Sale   2015-04-01      NA      TRUE
# 12:  Tom         Sale   2015-07-01      NA        NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `base R`:

`df` is first split according to `Name` and then, among each subset, for each `Sale`, it looks if there is an Email (Webinar) within 21 days from the Sale. Finally, the list is unsplit according to `Name`.
You just have to replace `FALSE` by `no` and `TRUE` by `yes` afterwards.

```
df_split <- split(df, df$Name)

df_split <- lapply(df_split, function(tab){
                                i_s <- which(tab[,2]=="Sale")
                                tab$Email21[i_s] <- sapply(tab[i_s, 3], function(d_s){any(tab[tab$ActivityType=="Email", 3] >= d_s-21)})
                                tab$Webinar21[i_s] <- sapply(tab[i_s, 3], function(d_s){any(tab[tab$ActivityType=="Webinar", 3] >= d_s-21)})
                                tab
                              })
df_res <- unsplit(df_split, df$Name)

df_res
#   Name ActivityType ActivityDate Email21 Webinar21
#1  John        Email   2014-01-01      NA        NA
#2  John      Webinar   2014-01-05      NA        NA
#3  John         Sale   2014-01-20    TRUE      TRUE
#4  John      Webinar   2014-03-25      NA        NA
#5  John         Sale   2014-04-01   FALSE      TRUE
#6  John         Sale   2014-07-01   FALSE     FALSE
#7   Tom        Email   2015-01-01      NA        NA
#8   Tom      Webinar   2015-01-05      NA        NA
#9   Tom         Sale   2015-01-20    TRUE      TRUE
#10  Tom      Webinar   2015-03-25      NA        NA
#11  Tom         Sale   2015-04-01   FALSE      TRUE
#12  Tom         Sale   2015-07-01   FALSE     FALSE
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", 
"John", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom"), ActivityType = c("Email", 
"Webinar", "Sale", "Webinar", "Sale", "Sale", "Email", "Webinar", 
"Sale", "Webinar", "Sale", "Sale"), ActivityDate = structure(c(16071, 
16075, 16090, 16154, 16161, 16252, 16436, 16440, 16455, 16519, 
16526, 16617), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Name", "ActivityType", 
"ActivityDate"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), index = structure(integer(0), ActivityType = c(1L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 10L)), class = "data.frame")
```