# Row Count in Group By if Date is Before the Current Row being Evaluated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate by `customer_id` the `num_opens_at_campaign_send`. This is dependant on the number of campaigns a customer has opened prior to each campaign being sent.

I can't figure out the best approach to do this in pandas, so any help would be appreciated. I'm thinking a groupby `customer_id` and an `apply` function to compare each `campaign_sent` date with all other dates in that column, but I'm unsure of the precise method to get the row counts to calculate the number of campaigns a customer has opened at the time of each campaign send.

The dataframe is as follows:

| customer_id | campaign_id | campaign_sent | opened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1234 | 2021-01-01 | True |
| b | 1234 | 2021-01-01 | True |
| c | 1234 | 2021-01-01 | False |
| a | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | True |
| b | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | False |
| c | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | True |
| a | 3333 | 2021-03-01 | True |
| b | 3333 | 2021-03-01 | False |
| c | 3333 | 2021-03-01 | True |

The desired output is:

| customer_id | campaign_id | campaign_sent | num_opens_at_campaign_send |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1234 | 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| b | 1234 | 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| c | 1234 | 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| a | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | 1 |
| b | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | 1 |
| c | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | 0 |
| a | 3333 | 2021-03-01 | 2 |
| b | 3333 | 2021-03-01 | 1 |
| c | 3333 | 2021-03-01 | 1 |

So for the first campaign `num_opens_at_campaign_send` is 0 for all because there were no campaigns prior to it.

As an example `customer_id` 'b' has 1 open when `campaign_id` 3333 is sent because they opened the first campaign (1234) but did not open the second campaign (2222) email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.groupby.transform` to compute the `num_opens_at_campaign_send` column. First group by the `customer_id`, now `num_opens_at_campaign_send` for a row is `cumulative sum of opened till the row` - `value of opened in that row`.

To make sure that `cumulative sum` is computed in the right order of date, first sort the dataframe by `campaign_sent` column.

Use:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ['campaign_sent'])
df['num_opens_at_campaign_send'] = ( df.groupby('customer_id')['opened']
                                       .cumsum() - df.opened)
df.drop(columns = 'opened', inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  customer_id  campaign_id campaign_sent  num_opens_at_campaign_send
0           a         1234    2021-01-01                           0
1           b         1234    2021-01-01                           0
2           c         1234    2021-01-01                           0
3           a         2222    2021-02-01                           1
4           b         2222    2021-02-01                           1
5           c         2222    2021-02-01                           0
6           a         3333    2021-03-01                           2
7           b         3333    2021-03-01                           1
8           c         3333    2021-03-01                           1
```

Comment: You would have to make sure that the df was date sorted in ascending order on  the `campaign_sent` column for this to work right?

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would this be done if you wanted `num_opens_at_campaign_send` for the last n days per `customer_id`? For example the last 30 days? Some form of rolling function? Again I'm struggling to get the right method.

Comment: I think resample will be needed as the data does have records for everyday

Comment: This may help: [Time aware rolling in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41643179/7831421)