# pandas get a sum column for next 7 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the sum of values for next 7 days of a column

my dataframe :

```
         date  value
0  2021-04-29      1
1  2021-05-03      2
2  2021-05-06      1
3  2021-05-15      1
4  2021-05-17      2
5  2021-05-18      1
6  2021-05-21      2
7  2021-05-22      5
8  2021-05-24      4
```

i tried to make a new column that contains date 7 days from current date

```
df['temp'] = df['date'] + timedelta(days=7)
```

then calculate *value* between date range :

```
df['next_7days'] = df[(df.date > df.date) & (df.date <= df.temp)].value.sum()
```

But this gives me answer as all 0.

intended result:

```
         date  value  next_7days
0  2021-04-29      1           3
1  2021-05-03      2           1
2  2021-05-06      1           0
3  2021-05-15      1          10
4  2021-05-17      2          12
5  2021-05-18      1          11
6  2021-05-21      2           9
7  2021-05-22      5           4
8  2021-05-24      4           0
```

The method iam using currently is quite tedious, are their any better methods to get the intended result.

Comment: Wouldn't for any column `x`, the expression `x > x` always be False? You can use `>=`

Comment: but i dont want to sum the current day's value

Comment: How big is the dataframe. Would a loop over all entries be feasible?

Comment: The solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642320/efficient-pandas-rolling-aggregation-over-date-range-by-group-python-2-7-windo seems like a good way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
tomorrow_dates = df.date + pd.Timedelta("1 day")
next_week_dates = df.date + pd.Timedelta("7 days")

df["next_7days"] = [df.value[df.date.between(tomorrow, next_week)].sum()
                    for tomorrow, next_week in zip(tomorrow_dates, next_week_dates)]
```

where we first define tomorrow and next week's dates and store them. Then `zip` them together and use `between` of `pd.Series` to get a boolean series if the date is indeed between the desired range. Then using boolean indexing to get the actual `value`s and `sum` them. Do this for each date pair.

to get

```
        date  value  next_7days
0 2021-04-29      1           3
1 2021-05-03      2           1
2 2021-05-06      1           0
3 2021-05-15      1          10
4 2021-05-17      2          12
5 2021-05-18      1          11
6 2021-05-21      2           9
7 2021-05-22      5           4
8 2021-05-24      4           0
```