# Rank most recent scores of students within a given date - 30 days window

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rank

Following is what my dataframe/data.table looks like. The `rank` column is my **desired** calculated field.

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('
             Name   Score         Date              Rank
             John    42         1/1/2018              3   
             Rob     85         12/31/2017            2
             Rob     89         12/26/2017            1
             Rob     57         12/24/2017            1
             Rob     53         08/31/2017            1
             Rob     72         05/31/2017            2
             Kate    87         12/25/2017            1
             Kate    73         05/15/2017            1
             ')
df[,Date:= as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
```

I am trying to calculate the rank of each student at every given point in time in the data within a 30 day windows. For that, I need to fetch the most recent scores of all students at a given point in time and then pass the rank function.

In the 1st row, as of `1/1/2018`, `John` has two more competitors in a past 30 day window: Rob with the most recent score of `85` in `12/31/2017` AND Kate with the most recent score of `87` in `12/25/2017` and both of these dates fall within the `1/1/2018 - 30` Day Window. John gets a rank of `3` with the lowest score of `42`. If only one students falls within `date(at a given row) - 30 day window`, then the rank is 1.

In the 3rd row the date is `12/26/2017`. So Rob's score as of `12/26/2017` is `89`. There is only one case of another student that falls in the time window of `12/26/2017 - 30` days and that is the most recent score(`87`) of kate on `12/25/2017`. So within the time window of `(12/26/2017) - 30` , Rob's score of `89` is higher than Kate's score of `87` and therefore Rob gets rank `1`.

I was thinking about using the framework from here [Efficient way to perform running total in the last 365 day window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600073/efficient-way-to-perform-running-total-in-the-last-365-day-window) but struggling to think of  a way to fetch all recent score of all students at a given point in time before using rank.

Comment: Rob's score as of 12/31 should also be 89 giving him rank 1 on row 2, right?

Comment: @Frank Hey Frank, I was thinking that as of 12/31, Rob's most recent score is 85 which is second to Kate's 87 on 12/25(which falls in the 12/31 - 30 day window).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
ranks = df[.(d_dn = Date - 30L, d_up = Date), on=.(Date >= d_dn, Date <= d_up), allow.cart=TRUE][, 
  .(LatestScore = last(Score)), by=.(Date = Date.1, Name)]

setorder(ranks, Date, -LatestScore)
ranks[, r := rowid(Date)]

df[ranks, on=.(Name, Date), r := i.r]

   Name Score       Date Rank r
1: John    42 2018-01-01    3 3
2:  Rob    85 2017-12-31    2 2
3:  Rob    89 2017-12-26    1 1
4:  Rob    57 2017-12-24    1 1
5:  Rob    53 2017-08-31    1 1
6:  Rob    72 2017-05-31    2 2
7: Kate    87 2017-12-25    1 1
8: Kate    73 2017-05-15    1 1
```

... using `last` since the Cartesian join seems to sort and we want the latest measurement.

*How the update join works*

The `i.` prefix means it's a column from `i` in the `x[i, ...]` join, and the assignment `:=` is always in `x`. So it's looking up each row of `i` in `x` and where matches are found, copying values from `i` to `x`.

Another way that is sometimes useful is to look up `x` rows in `i`, something like `df[, r := ranks[df, on=.(Name,Date), x.r]]` in which case `x.r` is still from the `ranks` table (now in the `x` position relative to the join).

---

There's also...

```
ranks = df[CJ(Name = Name, Date = Date, unique=TRUE), on=.(Name, Date), roll=30, nomatch=0]
setnames(ranks, "Score", "LatestScore")

# and then use the same last three lines above
```

I'm not sure about efficiency of one vs another, but I guess it depends on number of Names, frequency of measurement and how often measurement days coincide.

Comment: Was about to post a beast like `df[, rank := 
     df[.(iName = Name, iDate1 = Date - 30, iDate2 = Date), 
        on = .(Date >= iDate1, Date <= iDate2), by = .EACHI,
        .SD[order(x.Date), .SD[.N], by = Name][, frank(-Score)[Name == iName]]]
   $V1][]` grouping by `.EACHI` but yours is much more concise.

Comment: r:= i.r seems to magically clean up and sort the join between df and ranks on=.(Name, Date). What is i.r?

Answer (score 2):

A solution that uses `data.table` though not sure if it is the most efficient usage:

```
df[.(iName=Name, iScore=Score, iDate=Date, StartDate=Date-30, EndDate=Date), 
    .(Rank=frank(-c(iScore[1L], .SD[Name != iName, max(Score), by=.(Name)]$V1), 
        ties.method="first")[1L]), 
    by=.EACHI, 
    on=.(Date >= StartDate, Date <= EndDate)]
```

#### Explanation:

1) The outer square brackets do a non-equi join within a date range (i.e. 30days ago and latest date for each row). Try studying the below output against the input data:

```
df[.(iName=Name, iScore=Score, iDate=Date, StartDate=Date-30, EndDate=Date),
    c(.(RowGroup=.GRP), 
        .SD[, .(Name, Score, Date, OrigDate, iName, iScore, iDate, StartDate, EndDate)]),
    by=.EACHI,
    on=.(Date >= StartDate, Date <= EndDate)]
```

2) `.EACHI` is to perform `j` calculations for each row of `i`.

3) Inside `j`, `iScore[1L]` is the score for the current row, `.SD[Name != iName]` means taking scores not corresponding to the student in the current row. Then, we use the `max(Score)` for each student of those students within the 30days window.

4) Concatenate all these scores and calculate the rank for the score of the current row while taking care of ties by taking the first tie.

#### Note:

see `?data.table` to understand what `i`, `j`, `by`, `on` and `.EACHI` refers to.

---

#### EDIT after comments by OP:

I would add a OrigDate column and find those that matches the latest date.

```
df[, OrigDate := Date]

df[.(iName=Name, iScore=Score, iDate=Date, StartDate=Date-30, EndDate=Date), 
    .(Name=iName, Score=iScore, Date=iDate, 
        Rank=frank(-c(iScore[1L], 
                .SD[Name != iName, Score[OrigDate==max(OrigDate)], by=.(Name)]$V1), 
            ties.method="first")[1L]), 
    by=.EACHI, 
    on=.(Date >= StartDate, Date <= EndDate)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation. Instead of using max(Score) for each student within the 30 day window, my goal is to use the most recent score of those students. So as of 1/1/2018, John's 42 is compared against Rob's 85 which is the most recent(12/31) to 1/12018, not the max(score) 89 which is not the most recent as it happened on 12/26. John's 42 score is also compared against Kate's 87 which happens to be the highest score and also the most recent score of Kate(12/25) relative to 1/1/2018. What edit do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with following partial solution, encountered however problem - is it possible that there will be two people occuring with the same date?

if not, have a look at following piece of code:

```
library(tidyverse) # easy manipulation
library(lubridate) # time handling
# This function can be added to 
get_top <- function(df, date_sel) {
  temp <- df %>% 
    filter(Date > date_sel - months(1)) %>% # look one month in the past from given date
    group_by(Name) %>% # and for each occuring name
    summarise(max_score = max(Score)) %>% # find the maximal score
    arrange(desc(max_score)) %>% # sort them
    mutate(Rank = 1:n()) # and rank them
  temp
}
```

Now, you have to find the name in the table, for given date and return its rank.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setorder(df, -Date)

fun <- function(i){
    df[i:nrow(df), head(.SD, 1), by = Name] %$% 
        rank(-Score[Date > df$Date[i] - 30])[1]
}
df[, rank := sapply(1:.N, fun)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by joining to `df` those rows of `df` that are within 30 days behind it or the same date and have higher or equal scores.  Then for each original row and joined row Name get the joined row Name that is the most recent.  The count of the remaining joined rows for each of the original `df` rows is the rank.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("with X as
  (select a.rowid r, a.*, max(b.Date) Date
  from df a join df b
  on b.Date between a.Date - 30 and a.Date and b.Score >= a.Score
  group by a.rowid, b.Name)

  select Name, Date, Score, count(*) Rank 
  from X
  group by r
  order by r")
```

giving:

```
  Name       Date Score Rank
1 John 2018-01-01    42    3
2  Rob 2017-12-31    85    2
3  Rob 2017-12-26    89    1
4  Rob 2017-12-24    57    1
5  Rob 2017-08-31    53    1
6  Rob 2017-05-31    72    2
7 Kate 2017-12-25    87    1
8 Kate 2017-05-15    73    1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution (`dplyr` + `tidyr`):

```
df %>%
  complete(Name,Date) %>%
  group_by(Name)      %>% 
  mutate(last_score_date = `is.na<-`(Date,is.na(Score))) %>%
  fill(Score,last_score_date) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Score) & Date-last_score_date <30) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(Rank = rank(-Score)) %>%
  right_join(df)

# # A tibble: 8 x 5
# # Groups:   Date [?]
# Name       Date Score last_score_date  Rank
# <chr>     <date> <int>          <date> <dbl>
# 1  John 2018-01-01    42      2018-01-01     3
# 2   Rob 2017-12-31    85      2017-12-31     2
# 3   Rob 2017-12-26    89      2017-12-26     1
# 4   Rob 2017-12-24    57      2017-12-24     1
# 5   Rob 2017-08-31    53      2017-08-31     1
# 6   Rob 2017-05-31    72      2017-05-31     2
# 7  Kate 2017-12-25    87      2017-12-25     1
# 8  Kate 2017-05-15    73      2017-05-15     1
```

- We add all missing combinations of `Date` and `Name`
- then we create a column for the `last_score_date`, equal to `Date` when score isn't NA.
- by filling NAs down Score has become the *latest* score
- we filter out NAs and keep only scores that have < 30 days of age
- That's our table of valid scores by dates
- From there it's easy to add ranks
- and a final right_join on the original table gives us the expected output

**data**

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('
            Name   Score         Date   
            John    42         01/01/2018  
            Rob     85         12/31/2017
            Rob     89         12/26/2017
            Rob     57         12/24/2017
            Rob     53         08/31/2017
            Rob     72         05/31/2017
            Kate    87         12/25/2017
            Kate    73         05/15/2017
            ')
df[,Date:= as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
```