# Counting number of times Activity Types appear in the last 21 day Window

Tags: r, data.table

This is what my dataframe looks like. The two rightmost columns are my desired columns.

```
dt <- read.table(text='

    Name      ActivityType     ActivityDate  EmailLast21(Desired)     WebinarLast21(Desired)             
    John       Email            1/1/2014           1                  0  
    John       Webinar          1/5/2014           1                  1
    John       Webinar          1/20/2014          1                  2
    John       Webinar          3/25/2014          0                  1
    John       Email            4/1/2014           1                  1
    John       Email            4/20/2014          2                  0
    Tom        Email            1/1/2014           1                  0  
    Tom       Webinar           1/5/2014           1                  1
    Tom       Webinar           1/20/2014          1                  2
    Tom       Webinar           3/25/2014          0                  1
    Tom       Email             4/1/2014           1                  1
    Tom       Email             4/20/2014          2                  0

    ', header=T, row.names = NULL)
```

Based on a previous solution here:[Events in last 21 days for every row by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760733/events-in-last-21-days-for-every-row-by-name) I am trying the following

```
require(data.table)
    setDT(dt)
    dt[, ActivityDate := as.Date(ActivityDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
    setkey(dt, Name, ActivityDate)

    roll_index <- function(x, types, roll=21) {
      lapply(types, function(type) {
        idx = x[ActivityType == type][x, roll=roll, which=TRUE]
        as.numeric(idx)
      })
    }
    dt[, c("Email_21", "Webinar_21") := roll_index(dt, c("Email", "Webinar"))]
```

But the output is not what I want as I used as.numeric function instead of something that will count the number of times **webinar** or **email** appears in the last 21 days window. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: The two rightmost columns are my desired output

Comment: have a look at `cumsum`. Make a column/index of one each time you need to count and run `cumsum` on that. *Then* apply it in a moving average type situation.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer Thanks. I would use cumsum if I did not have that rolling 21 day restriction. I dont know how to incorporate time window restriction in the context of using cumsum.

Comment: Once you've got the first part working apply it to a subset based on the date of that line minus 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method which uses only base R and seems relatively straightforward could look like:

```
# ensure that ActivityType is a factor
  dt$ActivityType <- factor(dt$ActivityType)   
# convert character dates to Date types
  dt$ActivityDate <- as.Date(dt$ActivityDate, "%m/%d/%Y")  
# ensure that dt is ordered by Name and ActivityDate
  dt <- dt[order(dt$Name, dt$ActivityDate),]
# for each ActivityDate and Name, count the number of instances within a 21 day window for each ActivityType
  dt <- cbind(dt, t(sapply(split(dt, list(dt$ActivityDate, dt$Name)), 
                         FUN=function(y) { z= (dt$Name == y$Name & dt$ActivityDate <= y$ActivityDate & dt$ActivityDate > (y$ActivityDate -21));
                                      sapply(levels(dt$ActivityType), FUN=function(x) sum(z & dt$ActivityType == x )) } )) )
```

This version is somewhat faster and a bit simpler than the previous version.

**EXPLANATION**

I'll try to answer your question by going through the steps in the last statement  although this makes the answer a bit long.  I  thought of `dt` in your problem as providing two sets of overlappoing data.  First the `Name` and `ActivityDates` columns provide the set of names and dates for which results are required.  Second the `Name`, `ActivityDates`, and `ActivityTypes` columns provide the data for computing the results.  So,  the code does the following

1. `sapply` with `split` sets up the loop over all `Name-ActvityDates` pairs.  In ths case, `split` breaks `dt` into a list where each element of the list is a data frame containing a row of `dt`.  The code uses `sapply-split` since it passes the row as a data frame with all columns to its `FUN` argument. Rather than use a named function from an R package, the code defines a function using the usual function definition format i.e. function(argument) { statements using arguments }.  In this case, the function has no name and is called an anonymous function.
2. Now that we have set up the loop over `Name-AcivityDates` pairs, we will think of `dt` in the second way described above, as the source of data used to compute the results required for each row of `dt`.  The function `function(y)`  where `y` is the name of the argument for this function does this.  The first statement in `function(y)`  identifies all rows of `dt` which match the `Name` and the `ActivityDate` range of the input row `y` (a single-row data frame) where `y$Name` is the `Name` column and `y$ActivityDate` is the `ActivityDate` for the `ActivityDate` range we are trying to match.      The results of this matching process are stored in `z` as a logical vector where a value of `TRUE` in the `i-th` element of `z` indicates that the `i-th` row of `dt` matches `y` while a value of `FALSE` means no match.  `z` may contain matches for multiple values of `ActivityType` but it's important for the performance of the code that finding the rows of `dt` which match range defined by `ActivityDates` only be done once per row of `dt`.
3. The second statement of `function(y)` counts the number of matches in `z` for each value of `ActivityType`.  `sapply` loops over the unique values of `ActivityType` (e.g. Email and webinar), passes each value to the anonymous function `function(x)`, finds the rows in `dt` which match `x`, and forms a logical vector with `z` containing only the matches for that `Name`, `AcivityType`, and range of dates.   `z`  is available to `function(x)` since it was defined in `function(y)`, the parent environment of `function(x)`.     `sum` acting on a logical vector counts the number of `TRUE` elements which gives the counts reported in the results.
4. `sapply` returns a matrix with `ActivityType` as rows and `Name-ActivityDates` as columns so `t` is used to form the transpose which is then bound to `dt` using `cbind`.

I tried to make the code have good performance and be comprehensible.  If futher performance improvements are needed, the base R code can be made a bit faster  or this  approach could be moved to use either `dplyr` or `data.table` which might also help.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Hi WaltS, your solution is very elegant. I was wondering if you could kindly break down the last step. When we are doing dt$Name == y$Name, what is "y" here? Is it each element of the list "split(dt, list(dt$ActivityDate, dt$Name)"? In that case how does y$Name return anything? I had the same question about "dt$ActivityType == x". Kindly let me know.

Comment: See explanation above.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a detailed answer! It would be awesome if you can guide me regarding moving this approach to data.table.

Comment: Just curious but did you compare the execution times of this base R approach versus the `data.table` version in your later question?

Comment: data.table took about 1.87 hours. I don't remember exactly but base R was over 3 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Cast email/webinar to separate variables.

```
dc <- dcast(dt, Name + ActivityDate ~ ActivityType, fun.aggregate=length)
```

Then apply the answer below to get your rolling sum of each one by the 21 day window:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24400600/2573061

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!